# Can I represent 3D orientations as R^N vectors with continuous topology?

Tags: 3d, rotations

When I represent the orientations of 3D objects (with 3 degrees of freedom), can I embed them into R^N space in such a way that two orientations correspond to close vectors? So that the vector representation is at least locally smooth?

Like we do for 2D orientations: just take a complex number of unit length, and it nicely lays on the unit ring where close orientations correspond to close complex numbers.

Quarternions of opposite signs correspond to the same rotation [edited]

Comment: Can you provide an example of quaternions who sharply change sign ?

Comment: Do you mean rotations?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm mistaken, not the quarternions shaply change sign, but +q and -q correspond to the same rotation, right?

Comment: Indeed, it comes from the fact that a rotation of axis $v$ and angle $\alpha$ is the same in 3D as a rotation of axis $-v$ and angle $-\alpha$

Comment: but you can restrict yourself to quaternions whose real real part is $ \ge 0$

Comment: @Randall, could you explain me the difference between rotation and orientation in 3D? Maybe it's not the same. For example, I need to encode the position of a 3d object and its orientation (3dof), isn't orientation the same as rotation of that object from some "zero" position/orientation?

Comment: @stity, if I restrict myself to real part >= 0, I will have sharp discontinuities around a=pi degrees, right? For example, for small e > 0, and two rotations {pi - e, pi + e}, I have quarternions (e, 1, 0, 0), and (e, -1, 0, 0), which is big difference.

Maybe we can use something more tricky, like the square of the quarternion?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this topic, but here are some keywords for your further research: You are looking for an [embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#Topology_and_geometry) of [$\mathrm{SO}(3)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO(3)) (or equivalently, [$\mathbb{RP}^3$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space)) into $\mathbb R^n$. [It's possible to do this for $n=5$](https://mathoverflow.net/a/57598), but I don't know an explicit construction.

Comment: @Hexagonal I don't think you can have continuity and unicity if you are using the usual norm. Just like with angle, when you compare $2\pi-\epsilon$ and $\epsilon$ you need a comparison function that "wraps around" the discontinuity. In the case of the quaternions, I would suggest $d'(q_1,q_2)=\min(d(q_1,q_2), d(q_1,-q_2))$

Comment: @stity, yes, I already thought to regularize all the points to the same "side".

Comment: @Rahul, thank you for pointing out. They embed it topologically, but will it deform the space significantly? I want to keep distances approximately equally "stretched" over the space, but for topologists it's not an issue.

Maybe I formulated the problem too specifically. Actually, I want to do something like we do for position: compute statistics, mean, covariation matrix (local probability density as oriented gaussian), then I can combine the gauss clouds from different sensors and refine mean, but how to do it for the orientation...

Comment: @Hexagonal how do you define the mean of two rotation, even in 2D : what  is the mean of the rotations $\{0,\pi\}$ ? $\pi/2$ ? $3\pi/2$ ? What is the the mean of $\{2\pi-\epsilon, \pi-\epsilon\}$? is it close from the mean of  $\{0,\pi\}$ ? In fact, you can only get the value of the mean $\pm \frac{2k\pi}{n}$ where $n$ is the number of points in your set. Similarly, the mean of a 3D rotation does not really make sense to me...

Comment: There is nothing in your question about approximately preserving distances. This is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). You should edit your question to ask about what you really want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not exactly answer your question, but I've often used the Lie algebra associated with quaternions to deal with them in a local vector space (for state estimation purposes)

Let's say I have two quaternions $q_1$ and $q_2$.

$$\theta = 2\log(q_1^{-1} q_2) $$
$$ \theta \in \mathbb{R}^3 $$

Where the quaternion logarithm maps the the quaternion group to the associated lie algebra with:

$$ log(q) = \dfrac{q_v}{\lVert q_v \rVert}  \textrm{atan2}(\lVert q_v \rVert, q_w)$$

and the quaternion exponential maps back to the Lie group

$$ \textrm{exp}(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \lVert \theta \rVert \\ \textrm{sinc} \lVert \theta \rVert \theta \end{bmatrix} $$

The cool thing about this is that $\theta$ is a vector.  You can add and subtract them locally, then map back to the quaternion space.

[Hertzberg et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1119) defines new $\boxplus$ and $\boxminus$ operators which do this automatically, so you can almost *pretend* that quaternions are a vector space.

$$ q_1 \boxplus \theta = q_2 $$
$$ q_2 \boxminus q_1 = \theta $$

Depending on your application, you might be able to get away with just looking at the difference between quaternions in the algrebra ($\mathbb{R}^3$)

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the article!

(I don't see here any 'Accept' button, so I just say it's very helpful)

Comment: You should see a greyed-out check mark below the voting arrows.  Clicking it will Mark the question as answered.  :)

Comment: (marked as answered, thanks once more)